# ParentNode is undefined, but at debugger exists

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello everyone.

```
    removeBtn()
    {
      let btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
      let par = btn.parentNode;
      alert(par);
    }
```

There is only one button at page. When I debug this function(Mozilla firefox debugger), I saw that btn is actually element and debugger tells me that parentNode isn't empty, but par variable is undefined.

[image: Screen from debug session]

I don't understand this behavior. I tried this code at Edge, but same results.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array. You should choose from that arr one element.

```
 removeBtn()
 {
      let btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]; // index
      let par = btn.parentNode;
      alert(par);
 }
```

this will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize array thing because I have only one button.